# How can I calculate the 80% of the total of a column ? And get all the line that represents this 80%

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

So I have a data.frame and I want to only get the lines that represent 80% of the total of one column.

This is an example of my data.frame :

[image: This is an example of my data.frame]

I've tried the quantiles but that doesn't give me the result I was expecting.

```
x <- 1
total <- 0
while (total <= sum(reference$CA) * 80 / 100) {
  total <- total + as.double(reference[x, "CA"])
  x = x + 1
}
reference_80 <- reference[(1:x - 1),]
```

I can imagine that R can provide such things but I wasn't able to find it yet, also if my data.frame is very large it'll take a lot of time with my code because I'm using a loop that's why I was wondering if there is a function that could do the job.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: You mean how my data.frame look like ?

Comment: Yes, see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
reference[cumsum(reference$CA) < sum(reference$CA) * .8,]
```